# updating data in database and joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a social network database , Parents in the network can offer their young children to add some information about him, and the child can accept or deny.
i have 3 tables :

1. Parents(ID , child.ID)
2. Young(ID)
3. Parent_Help_Young(young_id , parent_id , reply BIT)

so i wrote a procedure for The Parent to provide info abt the child but there was a syntax error

```
CREATE PROC Provide_info_young @parent_id     INTEGER, 
                               @young_id      INTEGER, 
                               @y_name        VARCHAR(20), 
                               @y_dateofbirth DATETIME, 
                               @y_age         INTEGER, 
                               @y_school      INTEGER, 
                               @y_club        INTEGER 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE youngs Y 
             INNER JOIN parent_help_young P 
                     ON Y.id = P.young_id 
             INNER JOIN parents Parent 
                     ON P.parent_id = Parent.id 
      SET    Y.s_name = @y_name, 
             Y.date_birth = @y_dateofbirth, 
             Y.age = @y_age, 
             Y.school_id = @y_school, 
             Y.club = @y_club 
      WHERE  P.parent_id = @parent_id 
             AND P.young_id = @young_id 
             AND @young_id = Parent.child_id 
             AND P.reply = 1 
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MySQL syntax for `update` with `join`.  Try SQL Server syntax:

```
  UPDATE Y
  SET    s_name = @y_name, 
         date_birth = @y_dateofbirth, 
         age = @y_age, 
         school_id = @y_school, 
         club = @y_club 
  FROM   youngs Y 
         INNER JOIN parent_help_young P 
                 ON Y.id = P.young_id 
         INNER JOIN parents Parent 
                 ON P.parent_id = Parent.id 
  WHERE  P.parent_id = @parent_id 
         AND P.young_id = @young_id 
         AND @young_id = Parent.child_id 
         AND P.reply = 1 ;
```